# XmlDataDocument is obsolete, any thoughts on replacing it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

In Visual Studio 2010/.NET Framework 4.0, System.Xml.XmlDataDocument is marked as obsolete. Any thoughts on how to replace it with the least amount of work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this from another website:

pass Nothing for the XmlResolver and Evidence parameters
xformer.Load(xsDoc, Nothing, Nothing)